# In sharepoint 2013 event reciever setting the theme inheritance false

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, theme

Is there any way that we can set the theme inheritance property to false in the SharePoint web provisioning event receiver.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing `InheritsThemedCssFolderUrl` in `AllProperties` bag

Something like

```
spweb.AllProperties["__InheritsThemedCssFolderUrl"] = "True";
```

**Updated: ** datatype is string.